# WPF control's template source code reference

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I believe microsoft recently released the source code for WPF. I know there is already a source code reference for .Net library ([Source Reference](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/))

I saw microsoft source code for WPF controls as well couple of months back but now I'm unable to find one. Yes I googled it and binged it as well, but  not able to find it.

I know I could use reflector or `right click` on the control using blend and get the default template, but I wanted to find the complete source.

The reason I'm asking is I'm trying to create a complete window control (pop up dialog) and I wanted it's background and header color to be window's theme dependent. When I try to get the default template from blend, I don't get the complete window's template code. 
Please let me know if anyone knows anything about the source code or the complete template for wpf default window. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any update on this? I thought i heard sometime that wpf got open sourced, but my google skills can't find it

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not easy thing. As there're several components by which the 'Complete Window' control is templated.

You can get the reference of the complete window template by digging into this one:

https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro

MahApps provides Metro styled controls(Even the window.) and by looking into the style defined for Window, you might get what you want.

Thanks...

*Please mark this as answer if it helps you..*

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find all the source code in https://github.com/dotnet/wpf

I don't know if the source is complete, i at least could find most things i needed.